# How to set a rule for pads of just one component in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am designing a PCB for a STM32 MCU, whose PCB model contains pads very close to each other (clearance < 10mil). How can I set a rule for pads of this specific MCU (not other components) on my board in order to allow designing pcb with this model and meanwhile keep the predefined rule (clearance > 10mil) for other components? I am using Altium Designer version 13.2.

Comment: Eagle has a way to "accept" certain clearance anomalies and remember that setting when you redo a design rule check - is there something similar for altium?

Comment: You can set different tolerances for pad distances and trace distances. If no other component has pads this close, this might solve it. Other than that you might want to add the components to classes and set different rules. That said, these constraints are there for a reason, if your fab house can make pads <10mil apart on part for the STM32 it will also be able to do that on the rest of the board (10mil is pretty large and should be ok in most standard fab houses).

Comment: Most fans can handle clearances down to 4 mil with no cost premium, unless you're using very thick copper.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a rule that applies to objects associated with a specific footprint:

[image]

That said, most fab shops can handle clearances down to 4 mil with no cost premium, and generally they set pricing based on the tightest tolerance anywhere on a board in any case, so it might be easier to just lower the clearance rule for the whole board to whatever's needed to allow your STM32 footprint.